# Can Apple tell me what purchases a user has?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I'm aware of the restore functionality and have implemented it in my apps before, but still has holes in it. 
I'm trying to display customized screens based on what apps the user have. Without user interaction, I want to be able to ask apple to retrieve me the in-app purchases that belong to that user for this app? 
Other posts mention that I should always keep track of that via calling methods like:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey
```

But at the same time considers it insecure. 
I am currently storing the info in DB. That's easy, but consider the following scenario:

1. User downloads the app. My DB records that user has 0 in-app purchases. The user later purchases 1 in-app purchase. My DB records that too.
2. User deletes the app for whatever reason
3. After a while, he re-downloads the app. My DB at this point starts a fresh and records that the user 0 purchases.
4. the user sees the in-app purchase (he already bought) and clicks on purchase again.
5. Here, my execution flow stops and apple picks up... Apple alerts the user that he has already bought the in-app and offers to get it for free.

That message is for the benefit for the user only, and my app is unaware of that. I haven't been able to find a call to apple asking what purchases a user had made for my app? I too, wouldn't want the user to pay again, but be able to always know what purchases he has made in the past at any given point. Why is that information so sealed at apple side? They alrady know the user has may app and I am only asking about in-app purchases in that app.

I am using Xamarin.

Comment: This is what receipt validation is for. See `NSBundle appStoreReceiptURL` and the documentation of receipt validation as of iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the receipt file and then scan through it. It will list all purchases the user has made inside that app, whatever device it was on. This code will let you parse the file and see the purchases made: https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS

Comment: But I think this code needs modification / further implementation as it is not complete, so that no user gets the same code?

Comment: I think the user was asking for C# because he said Xamarin. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make your database store account information the user creates when they want to purchase something from your in-app extras. So in order to make that purchase they have to create a username and password for your app, thus giving you a way to keep track of who owns what in app content without having to ask apple.